# PostgreSQL keeps prompting for a password I never gave in PowerShell

Tags: windows, postgresql

I'm trying to set up postgresql to run locally on my windows machine. I've downloaded psql from postgresql.org and installed it. However, whenever I try to run the psql command from the command line it prompts me for a password that I never gave it for a user it seems to have automatically generated based on the user name of my computer.

In Powershell:

```
PS C:\Users\Theophilus> psql
Password: 
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "Theophilus"
```

Nothing I would use as a password works in this case. I've uninstalled and reinstalled postgres from my windows machine to see if maybe there was somewhere to input a password but I found nothing.

Additionally, running psql with the default username of 'postgres' results in the same problem.

```
PS C:\Users\Theophilus> psql -U postgres
Password for user postgres: 
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

Hopefully someone can help me.

Comment: you need to add a user for psql who you can log in with, try using the gui.

Answer (score 6):

That's because you're not providing a username in the command so it's using your current username that you're logged in as which doesn't have permission. You should use the `postgres` account.

```
 c:\path\to\psql.exe -U postgres
```

So in your case

```
PS C:\Users\Theophilus> psql -U postgres
```

https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/First_steps

Comment: Running the command the way you suggest results in: `Password for user postgres:` which is again something I don't know

Comment: @judgegrubb You set that password during installation. If you've lost/forgotten it, you'll need to reset the password for the `postgres` user in the database; search for "postgresql password reset windows" to find instructions.